# Using multiple fields for random points in polygons QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, point-in-polygon

I'm quite new to QGIS and I have a question about the 'random points in polygons' functionality.

Is it possible to use more than one field from the attibute table when using 'random points in polygons' (in the expressions field)?

Currently I can select a field from the attribute table to generate the number of points I want. But now I would like to select two fields from the attribute table and have their sum as the number of points. And of course giving them both a different color.

Is this possible to do in the expression field or elsewhere?

Current situation: 10 points in polygon X from one field in one color

=> Polygon X, 
Field A = 10,
(Field B = 0)

Desired situation: 10 points in polygon X from two fields in two colors

=> polygon X,
Field A = 5,
Field B = 5

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE@Vp'! Sure, you could use an expression like `sum( "Field A", "Field B")`. But you wouldn't be able to differentiate between them if you want to colour them according to which field was used. In which case you would need to run the tool twice for each field, add an attribute field to each output with a constant value (e.g. for the output which used "Field A", you could create a string field which has the value `A` for each point). Then finally merge both outputs. You can then apply a categorised or rule-based symbology to colour the output based on the unique fields.